# What can I do with Firefox's Browser Console which I can't with Web Console?

Tags: firefox, console

I have recently known that Firefox has a Browser Console (different than Web Console) which can be enabled setting `devtools.chrome.enabled` to `true`.

I have searched information about what can I do with it, but I have only found

> The Browser Console lets you see all JavaScript errors and logging in
>   the browser, including from Firefox code. To enable it, go to
>   about:config in the url bar and set devtools.chrome.enabled to true.
>   Activate it through with the menu Web Developer > Browser Console.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Debugging_JavaScript#Browser_Console)

I have discovered that Browser console is useful because I can see the errors in sandboxed GreaseMonkey scripts. But I guess it can do lots of interesting things, where can I find some info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) says it all (when I asked this question that page didn't exist, it was created the Aug 7, 2013 5:04:27 PM)

> ## Browser Console
>
> The Browser Console is like the [Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console), but applied to the whole
>   browser rather than a single content tab.
>
> So it logs the same sorts of information as the Web Console - network
>   requests, JavaScript, CSS, and security errors and warnings, and
>   messages explicitly logged by JavaScript code. However, rather than
>   logging this information for a single content tab, it logs information
>   for all content tabs, for add-ons, and for the browser's own code.
>
> Similarly, you can execute JavaScript expressions using the Browser
>   Console. But while the Web Console executes code in the page window
>   scope, the Browser Console executes them in the scope of the browser's
>   chrome window. This means you can interact with all the browser's tabs
>   using the [`gBrowser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser) global, and even with the XUL used to specify the
>   browser's user interface.
>
> To open the Browser Console, select "Browser Console" from the Web
>   Developer submenu in the Firefox Menu (or Tools menu if you display
>   the menu bar or are on Mac OS X):
>
> [image]
>
> You can see that the Browser Console looks and behaves very much like
>   the [Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console):
>
> - most of the window is occupied by a [pane that display messages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console#Message_Display_Pane)
> - at the top, a [toolbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console#Filtering_and_searching) enables you to filter the messages that appear
> - at the bottom, a [command line interpreter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console#The_command_line_interpreter) enables you to evaluate JavaScript expressions.
>
> ### Browser Console logging
>
> The Browser console logs the same sorts of messages as the Web
>   Console:
>
> - [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console#HTTP_requests)
> - [Warnings and errors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console#Warnings_and_errors) (including JavaScript, CSS, security warnings and errors, and messages explicitly logged by JavaScript code using
>     the [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console) API)
> - [Input/output messages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console#Input.2Foutput_messages): commands send to the browser via the command line, and the result of executing them.
>
> However, it displays such messages from:
>
> - web content hosted by all browser tabs
> - the browser's own code
> - add-ons.
>
> #### Messages from add-ons
>
> The Browser Console displays messages
>   logged by all Firefox add-ons.
>
> For example, here's a very simple [Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/index.html) add-on that just
>   logs an error when the user clicks an icon:
>
> ```
> // base-64 encoded icon, from http://edmerritt.com/'s "Vaga" icon set
> var icon = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9" +
> "hAAAC90lEQVR4Xk1STUgbWxQ+mbmZNGqcJGjaGBq7UUGpYCEUXMSFLgRBdKeIG6F06aKUt6irEks" +
> "R3JjWGAquSjeW8p6g3UQeCPKeJvCgRYP4QxK0TaPPGJPMZMzM3J4bM9ED35x7z/nOud+9c0yKooBh" +
> "h6FQV1lRZmRZ9l8riksplQjhedVssWQQm4SQwOMXL3YNviAIwBmb/WDwVT6X+1snZMz18GFLe3s7e" +
> "dLdDR2dncTl9bZQjhvD/D//zc+/gTtGjGJJkv5wtrTYHLIMaioFFL2sqgA8D3VWK9gcDjhvbLRlUq" +
> "mX38LhB93Pn08BGnewuNhVyOennW63zX5xAdfJJKiXl6Di1ewTExWvZrNQwriYz4PT4yH/Hx9PHm5" +
> "s3DRQ8M5CQ0OzXZKgnMmAjqfqmBBHRqC+pwcco6OgUQoaxhXMO3QdiMVCsvH462Qy2UxKkuTHO4N2" +
> "clIh6UimABVA1bOYztaYB1TpvH8fThMJj1vTholcLLqsHAeqJN0Wo9dwz0wtFkFjC6MRxus9Hrj68" +
> "QM0TRsgiiQRARtI2J0yQpVYzuVuGqA3VFCGchnqzGaQrq5A13Uf4fE/lzSNUJ4HDZMGObu1xXArv6" +
> "rOhDy5VALzvXtMQSvHC0Imz4YJA4ysVQvE3l7oCAaZZ/EaTPhLc4UC1DU1sQZJTsAJO0+ngXM6Qef" +
> "5mgKusRGY8aJYK2YqCfLSiQSIbW3sClGOx/EsZLP5M10Hs8sFOsdVyL/W1yERCkF6ba1WLGD+Fz6q" +
> "xObh6VOmIML5ZmZ26x2Odz+PjtRzfBzB6wXebgeTIEBubw/AYgEz7q2PHsE5HnK6vw/uvj7gRPEvV" +
> "LAKOEgVbL59u/zl2bPy2vQ03Z6bo7vBID0Ih+n3hQW6NTtLMUc/jo/TjaUlGovFtqPRaD97WFZcQ2" +
> "xlZSoSCJx8RvLy0BB97/fTD4OD9NPkJP0aCNB/IxGKhX/u7Oz0Mz5rYGKfuxaPx5tR2jBiAHM+9K2" +
> "IJK6jiAhi1efznRn837fI5BVWw7NCAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
>
> widget = require("sdk/widget").Widget({
>   id: "an-error-happened",
>   label: "Error!",
>   contentURL: icon,
>   onClick: logError
> });
>
> function logError() {
>   console.error("something went wrong!");
> }
> ```
>
> If you [build this as an XPI file](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/installation.html), then open the Browser Console,
>   then open the XPI file in Firefox and install it, you'll see an icon
>   in the Add-on bar:
>
> [image]
>
> Click the icon. You'll see output like this in the Browser Console:
>
> [image]
>
> For Add-on SDK-based add-ons only, the message is prefixed with the
>   name of the add-on ("log-error"), making it easy to find all messages
>   from this add-on using the ["Filter output"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console#Filtering_and_searching) search box. By
>   default, only error messages are logged to the console, although [you
>   can change this in the browser's preferences](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/console.html#Logging%20Levels).
>
> ### Browser Console command line
>
> Like the Web Console, the command line interpreter enables you to
>   evaluate JavaScript expressions in real time:
>
> [image]
>
> Also like the Web Console's command line interpreter, this command
>   line supports [autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console#Autocomplete), [history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console#Command_history), and various [keyboard shortcuts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console#Keyboard_shortcuts)
>   and [helper commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console#Helper_commands). If the result of a command is an object, you can [click on the object to see its details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console#Inspecting_objects).
>
> But while the Web Console executes code in the scope of the content
>   window it's attached to, the browser console executes code in the
>   scope of the chrome window of the browser. You can confirm this by
>   evaluating `window`:
>
> [image]
>
> This means you can control the browser: opening, closing tabs and
>   windows and changing the content that they host, and modify the
>   browser's UI by creating, changing and removing XUL elements.
>
> #### Controlling the browser
>
> The command line interpreter gets access to the [`tabbrowser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/tabbrowser) object,
>   through the `gBrowser` global, and that enables you to control the
>   browser through the command line. Try running this code in the Browser
>   Console's command line (remember that to send multiple lines to the
>   Browser Console, use Shift+Enter):
>
> ```
> var newTabBrowser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(gBrowser.selectedTab);
> newTabBrowser.addEventListener("load", function() {
>   newTabBrowser.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = "<h1>this page has been eaten</h1>";
> }, true);
> newTabBrowser.contentDocument.location.href = "https://mozilla.org/";
> ```
>
> It adds a listener to the currently selected tab's `load` event that
>   will eat the new page, then loads a new page.
>
> #### Modifying the browser UI
>
> Since the global `window` object is the browser's chrome window, you can
>   also modify the browser's user interface. On Windows, the following
>   code will add a new item to the browser's main menu:
>
> ```
> var parent = window.document.getElementById("appmenuPrimaryPane");
> var makeTheTea = gBrowser.ownerDocument.defaultView.document.createElementNS("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul", "menuitem");
> makeTheTea.setAttribute("label", "A nice cup of tea?");
> parent.appendChild(makeTheTea);
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> On OS X, this similar code will add a new item to the "Tools" menu:
>
> ```
> var parent = window.document.getElementById("menu_ToolsPopup");
> var makeTheTea = gBrowser.ownerDocument.defaultView.document.createElementNS("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul", "menuitem");
> makeTheTea.setAttribute("label", "A nice cup of tea?");
> parent.appendChild(makeTheTea);
> ```
>
> [image]

Comment: I think the XUL example that Mozilla put there is no longer available since Quantum. But the rest is pretty helpful. I wonder how one makes a fresh tab/window now... time to Google it. :)